# Setting up React in a large python project without Node

Tags: python, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement the front-end of a very large Python project with React.
It seems that most of the tutorials ask that we use Node to access the packages, is there any way to get around without them?

Initially I thought I could use it similarly to bootstrap or jquery where I just download the files or use the CDN and tag them in the HTML file, but it is not working.

Where do I go from here? Is there an easy way for me to install React?

Thanks!

Edit: I should probably add the code of what I am currently doing. I have tried to access the files which are on react's website, but nothing seems to be working, and from what I read in other questions and tutorials, they always ask to install via npm to make it all work, or so it seems...

```
 <div id='app'></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">

    var React = require ('react');
    var ReactDOM = require ('react-dom');

    var Test = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
            return(<h1>it is working! </h1>);
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: did you look here? https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html it has everything you need. However for a 'large python project' I think installing Node would make a lot of sense.

Comment: @azium yup, that is exactly what I used that didn't work.
As for Node, wouldn't I have to jump through some hoops to integrate the two?

Comment: Not at all. No integration needed whatsoever. Node for front-ends is just used as a build tool, not a server

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use React with your own flavor of Python framework (Tornado, Flask, Django, etc.). In the final deploy, you don't have to have any Node dependencies. I've run Tornado with React and just used NPM and webpack locally to manage package dependencies and trans-compile.

Comment: To make this answer clearer for OP, yes you should probably install Node, but it's just for development.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know.
Unfortunately it is still no help for the problem I am having :( It's still not working.